# Selenium : How to find the To field on spicejet.com website

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

How to find the Object in the 2nd instance in the code?

I try to find the object in the "TO:" field in one of the travel agency website.

I am able to find the 'FROM:" field, Can some one help me with this issue:

Here is my code:

```
driver.get("http://www.spicejet.com/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[value='HYD']")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@value='IXG']")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@value='HYD'])[2]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("(a[value='IXG'])[2]")).click();
```

Comment: Can you post the html source code for the webpage you're trying to select data from?

Comment: @PhotographyBum The website is mentioned in the post...

Comment: <a class="" value="AIP" text="Adampur (AIP)" onclick="javascript:$CityDropDown.SetSelectedValue(this);return false;" tooltip="" href="#"> Adampur (AIP)</a>

Comment: <a class="" value="IXG" text="Belagavi (IXG)" onclick="javascript:$CityDropDown.SetSelectedValue(this);return false;" tooltip="" href="#"> Belagavi (IXG)</a>

Comment: @Grasshopper, it's bad practice to rely on the website to be the same for the people that will look at this question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='RoundTrip']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@id,'originStation')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@value='DXB']")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@value='COK'])[2]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Css selector for **'From'** input - `"input#ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT"`

Css selector for **'To'** input - `"input#ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTXT"`

Xpath selector for **choosing 'From' city option (Kozhikode)** - `"//div[@id='glsctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTNR']//ul/li/a[starts-with(normalize-space(.),'Kozhikode')]"`

Xpath selector for **choosing 'From' city option (Kozhikode)**) - `"//div[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR']//ul/li/a[starts-with(normalize-space(.),'Kozhikode')]"`

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your question you are *able to find the 'FROM:" field* so to select a destination from the **TO** field you can use the following code block to select **Agartala** as a destination :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.spicejet.com/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[value='HYD']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#dropdownGroup1 li a[text*='Agartala']")).click();
```

Browser Snapshot :

[image: Agartala]